# Run micro AWS EC2 and RDS instances simultaneoulsy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a small doubt regarding the AWS free micro tier instances. If i run a EC2 micro instance and RDS micro instance for one month (720 hours each) will i get billed since the 750 hours free quota will be crossed when both are combined ?? Or free tier usage is calculated separately for each instances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The free tiers are independent by service, so as long as your EC2 instances don't go over 750 hours per month (and the instance types are eligible), and your RDS instances don't go over 750 hours per month (and the instance types are eligible), you'll be within the free tier.

So in your case, using 720 hours for EC2 and 720 hours for RDS with small enough instances would be free (for the first 12 months of AWS membership).

Comment: Got it.. Thank you @Tom